# Multi-step config in logback with clojure tools.logging

Tags: clojure, logback

I'm trying to use a custom appender in a clojure application using logback & clojure tools.logging.

My config looks like this:

```
<appender name="Sentry" class="net.kencochrane.raven.logback.SentryAppender">
    <dsn>some-dsn</dsn>
</appender>
```

This results in the following runtime error:

```
 The following loggers will not work because they were created during the default configuration phase of the underlying logging system.....
```

A quick google search turns up a document to use a JoranConfigurator programatically to perform a multi-step configuration, but I actually don't see an exposed method in tools.logging to perform multi-step configuration.  Any advise other than modifying tools.logging?  Am I missing something obvious?   Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`tools.logging` doesn't do any configuration of the underlying logging system. In the case of logback it just talks to the logging system via slf4j. The configuration of the actual logging is totally on the logback side.

Comment: Kotarak, thanks for the reply.  In this case the error is generated because of how slf4j behaves, as tools.logging is currently how I interact with slf4j, it seems the natural place for me to looking for a solution (feel free to disagree). Also tools.logging looks like it does interact to a degree with underlying implementations already, in src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging/impl.clj I see it testing if it can load classes from log4j/etc and then extending the loggers. It seems reasonable to provide required interfaces with the underlying system in my mind. If you see a better solution lmk

Answer (score 0):

An easy way might be to use a `logback.xml` config file and Logback dependencies with clojure/tools.logging. Based on [Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/logback/) it looks like you need the following dependencies:

```
[org.clojure/tools.logging "0.3.1" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]
[org.slf4j/slf4j-api       "1.7.25"]
[org.codehaus.janino/janino     "3.0.7"]  ; for conditional config processing
[ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.2.3"]
[ch.qos.logback/logback-core    "1.2.3"]
[com.getsentry.raven/raven-logback "8.0.2"]
```

The [Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/logback/) page also has snippets of Logback XML config that you can use. For MDC attributes, you may want to take a look at [Cambium](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/cambium).

Comment: Fwiw, if you include logback-classic, you'll get logback-core and slf4j-api.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple setup using `sentry-java-logback`,
with deps:

```
[org.clojure/tools.logging  "0.4.1"]    
[ch.qos.logback/logback-classic  "1.2.3"]    
[io.sentry/sentry-logback "3.2.0"]
```

and logback.xml:

```
<!-- Sentry -->
<appender name="SENTRY" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <options>
        <dsn>https://........</dsn>
        <release>1.0.0</release>
        <serverName>ABCDE</serverName>
        <environment>production</environment>
    </options>
    <minimumBreadcrumbLevel>DEBUG</minimumBreadcrumbLevel>
</appender>

<!-- ....THIS MIGHT CHANGE.... -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SENTRY"/>
</root>
```

you can read more on [Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/logback/)